# How can i call my provider model into initState method

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

i have several widgets use my provider as a condition , and i need one call to access my provider to whole widget from init state instead of wrapping every widget into my provider and it's `consumer`

this is my `provider`

```
class ProviderForFiltter extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool isFiltterrr = true ;

  bool get isFiltter => isFiltterrr;

  void changeStatus(bool status){
    isFiltterrr = status;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

this is my `main.dart`

```
class Myproject extends StatefulWidget {
  const Myproject ({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Myproject State createState() => _Myproject State();
}

class _Myproject State extends State<Myproject > {



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  
      
          Provider(
               create: (BuildContext context) {
                return ProviderForFiltter();
               },
               child: const MaterialApp(
                  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,

                  home: WelcomeScreen()


            ),
             ),

    );
  }
}
```

this is my `Stful` Widget

```
ProviderForFiltter? isF ;
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
     // i tried this but it always give me errors that is isF  null value
     WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      isF = context.read<ProviderForFiltter>();
    }); 
       // also itried this but it don't work 
    isF = Provider.of<ProviderForFiltter>(context, listen: false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {




    return Scaffold(
      body: Text('change'),
    )

  }

}
```

in the fact i need to use it's bool value as condition into Consumer and change it

i hope any help guys

Comment: Have you tried section `I have an exception when obtaining Providers inside initState. What can I do?` in https://pub.dev/packages/provider page?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to deal with this.

The first option (which I use) is to add a Post Frame Callback like so:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
  aProvider = Provider.of< aProvider >(context, listen: false);
});
```

Alternatively, you could override the didChangeDependencies method to get the provider value once initState has been called - remembering to set the listen value to false.

Answer (score 0):

is better don't do use Provider in initState, but you can use Future.delayed
because you need context

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
     // i tried this but it always give me errors that is isF  null value

   Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
  
     WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      isF = context.read<ProviderForFiltter>();
    }); 
       // also itried this but it don't work 
    isF = Provider.of<ProviderForFiltter>(context, listen: false);
   });
  }
```

Comment: thanks but do you think this code  is deserve to be Answer!? 1000 seconds like really ? and which code exactly to put it as what you mentioned since i have no idea what is the code exactly

Comment: your provider code

Comment: Can you please make favor to me and  delete the answer  , because no one would wait 1000 seconds , beside it didn't work too , and thank you so mush for trying to help Javad

Comment: Delaying for a full second is a very bad idea. It may crash your app, delay your widget tree from building for the first time, or cause the filter provider value to only be read a second after the first 'frame' of the UI is built.

Answer (score 0):

providers need **context**, in order to access it for one time you should override **didChangeDependencies**

```
 @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
   ///access provider here and update your state if needed,
   ///this will be called one time just before the build method
     **isF = Provider.of<ProviderForFiltter>(context, listen: false);**
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and regarding the documentation of provider this should be the answer.

> "This likely happens because you are modifying the ChangeNotifier from
> one of its descendants while the widget tree is building."

In my case i am calling an http api async where the future is stored inside the notifier. So i have to update like this and it is working.

```
initState() {
  super.initState();
  Future.microtask(() =>
    context.read<MyNotifier>().fetchSomething(someValue);
  );
}
```

The best way is to use like this (when there's no "external parameter".

```
class MyNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  MyNotifier() {
    _fetchSomething();
  }

  Future<void> _fetchSomething() async {}
}
```

source : https://pub.dev/packages/provider

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different method called `didChangeDependencies` to get the value from the provider after the `initState` method is called. Also, make sure to set the `listen` value to `false`.

```
   @override
      void didChangeDependencies() {
        super.didChangeDependencies();
         final filtterData = Provider.of<ProviderForFiltter>(context, listen: false);
      }
```